# Mail is not receiving to the user

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
namespace WebApplication1
{

    public partial class BatchEmail : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow item in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                string Email_Address = item.Cells[1].Text.Trim();
                MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
                msg.From = new MailAddress("khawarsaleem90@gmail.com");
                msg.To.Add(Email_Address);
                msg.Subject = TextBox1.Text;
                msg.Body = TextBox2.Text;
                SmtpClient smt = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
                smt.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("khawarsaleem90@gmail.com", "mypass");
                smt.EnableSsl = true;
                smt.Send(msg);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The user is not receiving the email, and Visual Studio isn't showing any errors? What did I do wrong?

Comment: send an email to yourself and see if you receive it. If yes, your code works. Then the issue could be it is going to the recipients junk folder or the recipients mail server is blocking it. There can be many reasons but start there.

Comment: I tried to mail myself but mail is not receiving to me. What should i do?

Comment: put a try catch around `Send` method and see what the exception is: `try { smt.Send(msg)} catch(Exception ex) { var ex2 = ex; // See what the issues is}`

Comment: I tried try catch exception but not succeed.

Comment: What do you mean not succeeded? I did not say it will succeed. I said check what the exception is so we can see what the issue.

Comment: Try catch exception didn't tell the what the exception is...

Comment: So there was no exception?

Comment: Yes there was no exception.

Comment: Please make sure that your emailId and password given is correct or not

Comment: I check it my id and password, it is correct

Answer (score 0):

I think it's about your gmail configurations. Click [**here**](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) and chose "**Open**". Then try again.

Comment: I tried to gmail configuration on this link but mail is not receiving. Tell me the other options to do this correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these lines:

```
smt.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smt.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use .Trim(), it may not see the correct e-mail addresses to send or may be null. Add your project a breakpoint and tell us what it says when you operate it. You can use this codes;

```
    try
        {
           foreach (GridViewRow item in GridView1.Rows)
           {
             string Email_Address = item.Cells[1].Text.Trim();
             MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
             msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
             msg.From = new MailAddress("khawarsaleem90@gmail.com");
             msg.To.Add(Email_Address);
             msg.Subject = TextBox1.Text;
             msg.Body = TextBox2.Text;
             SmtpClient smt = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
             smt.Credentials = new
             System.Net.NetworkCredential("khawarsaleem90@gmail.com", "mypass");
             smt.EnableSsl = true;
        try
            {
             smt.Send(msg);
             }

           catch (Exception ex)
              {
               throw new Exception(ex.Message.ToString());
              }
           }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw new Exception(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: There was no exception show. But was mail not receiving.

Comment: Tried to use breakpoint..? You will just follow the parameters step by step to see each values correct or not even you don't have an exception fault.

Comment: I tried to use a break point & follow the line by line code but there was no exception in this code...